# jQuery-Datatables Change ajax columns with html codes

Tags: jquery, datatable, datatables

I'm, using ajax request to get data to make my datatables, but I need change de columns with html's tags and content.

My datatables resquest is:

```
var oTable1 = $('#sample-table-2').dataTable({
    "language": {
        "url": "/assets/js/Portuguese-Brasil.json"
    },
    "aoColumnDefs": [{
        "bSortable": true, "aTargets": [0, 1, 2],
        "bSortable": false, "aTargets": [1, 2]
    }],
    "ajax": {
        "url": "/Clientes/GetClientes/",
        "dataSrc": "",
        "dataType": "json",                   
    },
    "columns": [
        { "data": "Nome" },
        { "data": "<strong>StatusDesc</strong>" },
        { "data": "<span>StatusDesc</span>" },
    ],                               
});
```

But when this table is render, the html code inside columns doen't work.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Use `sTitle`

```
{ "sTitle": "offer name<span style='display:none;'>offer_name</span>",  
  "data": "offer_name"
},
```

Comment: Yes, but `title` can also be used -> https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.title `sTitle` is the old hungarian notation naming style (but still works)

Comment: @sergiodebcn is possible send array inside data, and pass two or more data for one sTitle?!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't do that as you want it to do (at least, if I understood your "question" correctly).
The datatables already have classes for each element, e.g. the column headers are usually called *DataTables_sort_wrapper*. So what comes to mind is, you could change the appearance of those column headers with css and/or jQuery. E.g. you can find the n'th column appearance by using the jQuery .eq() function

```
$(".DataTables_sort_wrapper").eq(n).css(...)
```

Hope this helps.

Cheers